# Can I use discord.js with discord-rpc, with discord-rpc powering the *bot's* RPC?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord-rpc

I want to use discord-rpc in my bot, to give the bot a rich presense with buttons.
I can't find any information anywhere on how to do it, starting to think it's not doable tbh.

If I cannot do that, How do I add buttons to my bot's RPC/Rich Presence without streaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rich presence (using `discord-rpc`) is designed for apps and games, and not for bots or remote machines. The library works by checking for an open discord instance **on the same device** as the node.js server and if it is running, send the RPC info. Note that it must be on the same device.

Therefore, if you are running the bot on another machine to your users, this is not possible. If you happen to running the server on the same machine as your client, you can use the library and configure the RPC like normal. You can follow the [example](https://github.com/discordjs/RPC/blob/master/example/main.js) on how to do so.

Do also note that `discord-rpc` is "depreciated in favour of Discord's Game SDK", so expect it not to work in the future.